# How to swipe UIPageViewController from Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uinavigationbar, uipageviewcontroller, tinder

I am trying to make a `UIPageViewController` which can also be swiped from the navigation bar. Tinder ios app has a good example of this.

I cannot add the navigation bar inside the content view controllers, because the navigation bar is dynamic and animates as you swipe between pages.

So far my architecture is like this:

MainVC: UIVC
-Contains UIPageViewController inside it
-Contains Navigation bar inside it
-Contains data for VC1 and VC2

How do I achieve swipe input from navigation bar and affect UIPageVC?

[image]

Comment: I am not sure but I think you add UIView on navigation bar and on that view swipe call that method where you swipe UIPageView.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem and created a repo about it:

https://github.com/goktugyil/EZSwipeController

Its more like Snapchats navigation, which means the navigation bar does not animate but it works well.